Determining if a Go program has changed from a previous build
In a CI/CD system, I need a way to check if the hash of the source code for a Go executable has changed. I have the source code and the executable. I only want to deploy the built executable if it's functionally different from the last one that was deployed ("functional" meaning the change actually has an impact, i.e. not just a different timestamp).
There doesn't seem to be any straightforward way of calculating the hash of all source files that go into a build. You'd somehow have to parse the imports, recursively, and follow that through each file in each import. go.mod isn't super helpful for hash of dependencies since in a project that has more than one executable, the dependencies file will include dependencies for executables other than the one being built, so a change there doesn't necessarily mean a change in the executable.
The hash of the executable itself changes on each build, sometimes. If I build it and re-build it myself on my local machine (deleting it between builds), it remains consistent. If I build it on two different virtual machines from the same source code, it changes, so I assume it's injecting some sort of compile machine ID into the executable. So, I can't rely on this to tell if it's changed.
Is there any way to tell, particularly in a CI/CD context, if a Go executable (or source) has functionally changed from a previous build?

You probably want to read Perfectly Reproducible, Verified Go Toolchains

That's an interesting read. My understanding is that they're only talking about the Go toolchain itself though, not programs that are built with the toolchain.

Sorry, I must have misremembered that touching on general binaries too. Though it’s for the same issue, there are also some comments here which may be useful https://github.com/golang/go/issues/57120. You can get package hashes from DebugInfo, but that doesn’t include main, though it may help pinpoint which packages you need to track in your case.

[1/2] Based also on «I'm not sure this works for a package with multiple executables», I would propose to check the hash of the Git subtree containing the subpackage and either the hashes from debuginfo (can be grabbed via go version -m <executable_image_file>) or the hashes of go.mod and go.sum (if vendoring is used, then one can also get the hash of the vendor/ subtree). It's still an approximation, but pretty close, I would say. To make the measure precise, one would need to list all packages the code in main of the subpackage of interest imports, recursively, select only those…

[2/2] …which are local (i.e. rooted at what go.mod declares), map them to the filesystem and take hashes of Git trees of all of them. The hash or a Git tree can be taken via git ls-tree). Dealing with projects incorporating multiple modules (as opposed to packages) will be more tricky but the general idea is the same, I think.

OK, [3/2]. Also, if the commit from which the last shipped (i.e. "reference" binary) is known, you can just diff the current commit against that one using git diff --name-only to get the list of files known do have been changed; this list can then be filtered using one or more sets of criteria to get the idea of what had changed. This still need to be combined with figuring out whether any 3rd-party deps have changed as well.

In most cases, only change to *.go, go.mod and go.sum would change the executable functionally. The easiest way to detect these changes is by using git
if git diff --names-only HEAD HEAD~ | grep -E '\.go$|^go\.mod$|^go\.sum$' > /dev/null; then
    echo "Executable changed"
else
    echo "No changes found."
fi

git diff --names-only will give you a simple list of changed files between two commits, e.g.
go.mod
go.sum
main.go
internal/util.go

You would always use HEAD for the current commit. All you have to do is to find the base commit from which to calculate the diff. It could be master or another base branch or tag.
In my example I used HEAD~ which is the commit just before current HEAD.
If you have multiple executables that use subsets of files in a repo, you could place subdirectories as well as individual files into a pattern file and then use
if git diff --names-only HEAD HEAD~ | grep -f exec-A > /dev/null; then
    echo "Executable A changed"
fi

File exec-A would look like this
module-a/main.go
module-a/go.mod
internal/model
internal/logic


I'm not sure this works for a package with multiple executables (all sharing the same go.mod file) though, does it? Say you have a sub-package that is only used by half of the executables, and it changes. You can't just do a --diff on the whole repo for .go files because then all of the executables that don't use this sub-package will also be re-built even though they don't need to be. Essentially, your solution works when there's a single main() function per repo, but not when there are multiple.

True. Then any solution will have to somehow isolate these subsets. If you have a list of subdirectories that contribute to each executable, you could apply my approach by modifying grep command to use a pattern file instead. Answer updated.
